# PHP Echo stops when space in filename occur

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm trying to show an pdf file stored local in the browser with this code:

```
<p><a href=<?php
$sql = "select title from tasks where taskPK='".$_SESSION['task']."'";
$res = $db->query($sql);
if (!$res) {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$db->errno}] {$db->error}");
}
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $rad= $row['title'];
echo ("files/".$id."/".$rad.".pdf"); }?> > See PDF </a> </p>
```

This should go into the right folder and get the file and then show it. But my problem is that if the name of the file has an space for example "peter pan.pdf"
Then it won't work. The URL is supposed to be localhost/upload/files/9/Peter%20Pan.pdf
But that doesn't happen. The URL is localhost/upload/filer/9/Peter
It stops when the space hits and the file doesn't show.

But if the filename is connected with a - like this: "Peter-Pan.pdf" it works.
Then the URL becomes localhost/upload/filer/9/Peter-Pan.pdf
And the PDF shows.

Whats the problem? Sorry if it is a bit messy.

$id is the user wich becomes 9 in the URL

The problem should be in here but i can't figuire it out:

```
echo ("files/".$id."/".$rad.".pdf"); }?> > See PDF </a> </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White space is an illegal URL character. Use urlencode to clean `$rad`.

```
 $rad = urlencode($row['title']);
```

Regards,

EDIT:

```
$rad = rawurlencode($row['title']);
```

This is the reference to [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode)

Comment: It worked! Just needed to use rawurlencode
Thank you!!